# Drupal 6 Webforms sends duplicate emails

Tags: 6, webforms, emails

A user fills out a webform that I created and it gets emailed me. Sometimes I get duplicate emails when they fill it out. I'm thinking that this is because they are hitting the submit button multiple times.

Is there a way to avoid these duplicate emails from happening? I use the smtp authentication support module and gmail to send the request out. Perhaps it's taking too long connect with gmail and the user is getting impatient, thus feeling the need to press the button continuously.

Comment: I ended up using the hide submit module. http://drupal.org/node/338935

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can deactive the submit button after it was clicked with custom javascript.

I write a sample below:

```
Drupal.behaviors.FormSubmitDisable = function (context) {
  $('YOUR BUTTON ID').click(function () {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
  });
};
```